# The best way to check that text has correct encoding and displayed well

Tags: java, testing, encoding, webdriver

I'm looking for the way to write the JUnit test which will check that the page's or snippet's text is displayed correctly(has the correct encoding).
How to determine that string is well-displayed and not looks like "????? ?? ?????" or "�����@�����".

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty tricky, maybe get the byte[] array from the original String, put it in a new String with the tested/desired encoding, and from this new String fetch each char and look it up if it's a valid/printable char ? I never tried this, so I don't guarantee it works ... but I think you could try it :)